# how to share software on a windows network

Tags: windows-server-2008

I've used linux for years and basically installed all software onto one linux box into /usr/local and then used nfs to mount that directory over the network so I could use the same software on multiple computers.

Is there a way to do this with windows? Perhaps using windows servers?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You could just install remote desktop connection on the windows box with the software you want to use.  You can configure the remote desktop group policy for `x` number of connections and also allow the "server" box in question to be used at the same time as someone else is logged into it remotely.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately, Linux programs are all self contained in a single folder whereas Windows programs install components into various folders within the OS so you can't just connect the main program subdirectory and start running it since your computer won't have the files loaded locally.

That said, you could run something like Terminal Services where you load the application on the server and connect to the server and run a virtual session and run the program from that virtual session.